# How can I convert an android rom from 32bit to 64bit?

Tags: rom, android-10

My phone (Samsung Galaxy A10s) is a little unknown phone and it has few custom roms for it, I want one that is 64bits, arm64 and android 10 or 9, I didn't find any, so I wanted to make one myself, I read a lot and I know how to do most of what I want, but I don't know how to transform the rom into 64bits, my cell phone supports 64bits but it is in 32bits mode, and even though there is no 64bit rom for it, does anyone know a way for me to transform it in 64bit?

Comment: If you only have a binary ROM this is impossible. Theoretically if you would have all the sources of the ROM (kernel and all Android parts) you could compile a 64bit ROM from it, but there are two problems: usually you don't have everything in source so pre-compiled parts will still be 32bit so you would have to remove them (-> lose of functionality). Additionally your phone has only 2GB RAM which is in my opinion the main reason for the 32bit builds as 64bit builds require slightly more RAM and RAM is already short on your phone.

Comment: flash this [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4232981) and install 64 bit a/b GSI by phhusson